# Get data from server and display

Tags: javascript, sql, json

I need to display the comments on my page by fetching from database.

I am able to get dummy test data from .json file but when I try to connect it with data base url it is not getting the data.

I am using js handlebar template to loop the data in html page.

Here is my js to fecth the data

```
var getData = function () {
      console.group("getData()", "Fetching data from server at", R.settings.endPoints.incoming.getData);

      var promise = $.ajax({
        url: R.settings.endPoints.incoming.getData
      });

      console.log("getData()", "Returing the promise", { promise: promise });

      console.groupEnd();

      return promise;
    };
```

DB url is set with .getdata like below

```
endPoints: {
          incoming: {
            getData: "http://localhost:8080/rest/review/getReview"
          },
          outgoing: {
            sendData: "http://localhost:8080/rest/review/createReview"
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function is asynchronous by default so you need to put your processing/display code into the [deferred.done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) method like so:

```
var promise;

$.ajax({
  url: R.settings.endPoints.incoming.getData
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    console.log(msg);
    promise = msg;
  });
```

However, if you want to perform a synchronous request, do something like this:

```
var promise = $.ajax({
        url: R.settings.endPoints.incoming.getData,
        async: false
      });
```

Note that according to the official documentation:

```
As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; 
you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the 
corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the 
deprecated jqXHR.success().
```